# Camel 2.24.2 : PropertiesComponent override with environment variable

Tags: apache-camel

I am attempting use the `PropertiesComponent` and reading a property file that is in my classpath. I have built a standalone executable jar and I am using the camel `Main` class - no spring boot.

However, I would like to override one of those properties using environment variables, but it is not working. I am able to override it using the `-D`, but the documentation indicated that it is possible to override it using an environment variable.

Here is the sample code snippets

```
    Main main = new Main();
    main.addRouteBuilder(new HelloRoute());
    main.bind("doWork", new DoWork());
    PropertiesComponent pc = new PropertiesComponent();
    pc.setLocation("classpath:app.properties");
    main.bind("properties", pc);
    main.run();
```

Here is the property file

```
account.route.id=account_route_get
account.route.get=account_route_get_description
startup_route=false
```

And here is my route where I am attempting to use it. I am attempting to override the `startup_route` and it does not work correctly.

```
       rest("/account")
            .get("/{name}")
                .consumes("application/json")
                .outType(Account.class)
                .route()
                    .id("{{account.route.id}}")
                    .description("{{account.route.get}}")
                    .autoStartup("{{startup_route}}")
                    .to("log:{{account.route.get}}?level=INFO")
                    .to("bean:doWork?method=info(${header.name})")
            .endRest()
```

I found this [CAMEL-13502](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13502) but it is in a different Camel version, and I am wondering if this is also relevant for Camel 2.24.2

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to explicitly call out that you want the variable from the OS environment variables.

If you did want to do that, you could state

```
.autoStartup("${env:STARTUP_ROUTE}")
```

but if you are wanting a more dynamic solution, another option could be to create a

```
choice()
```

that first checks if the environment variable of that name exists, and if not, to default to the one in the properties file.

```
.when("${env:STARTUP_ROUTE} != null")
.autoStartup("${env:STARTUP_ROUTE}")
.otherwise()
.autoStartup("{{startup_route}}")
```

Finally, the Camel documentation of Property Component also states:

#### You can control these modes using the systemPropertiesMode and environmentVariableMode options on the properties component.

When I ran a sample in my project, I did have the ability to configure the systemPropertiesMode, but I didn't have an option for environmentVariableMode so unsure if that is a feature of a higher level Camel version than I'm using.

Comment: Thank you. I will use the ```when``` as suggested. That's really clever. I was also able to override using an ```-D``` argument (i.e systemProperty), but I guess I was thinking along the lines of Spring Boot where it allows overrides via environment variables and I was hoping Camel would offer something similar (of course, I can use Spring Boot + Camel to do this as well)